# Loading Data into an MVC View without reloading the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am building an MVC Web Application with a cshtml + Angular front-end. An important aspect of the application is for the View to update the angular data-table automatically when new Data is retrieved from the custom Data Service.

The Data Service is accessed via an API call in a C# Class on the backend which gets fresh data as a ViewModel List<> on a set interval (roughly 5 minutes) which it then caches. The ViewModel List<> is then passed to the view as an ActionResult parameter `return View(List<model>)`, serialized in our Angular controller and displayed in a table using ng-repeat.

I am relatively new to MVC and right now the only way I know how to get Data from a controller into a View is by passing it directly as an ActionResult parameter. As a result the only way for me to get data into the view requires me to reload the entire page via an explicit action (HTTPPOST, Forced Refresh, FormSubmit etc).

I want to try and use Angular and maybe AJAX(?) or a similar library, to "ask" the Controller that makes the API call and caches the data if there is new data every 10 seconds or so. Then, if there is new data (which there will be once ever ~5min) it will load that data into the View *in the background* WITHOUT reloading the page, so that Angular can Serialize it and then reload just the table.

This is just to enable users to get the most current data without having the make an explicit action or refresh the page.

I know how to do every part of this except getting the Angular to ask the C# class that makes the API Call if it has made a new Service Call (and stored it in the ViewModel) and then "pulling" the fresh data from that ViewModel into the view without having to return an ActionResult

Edit:

Since this is where most of our problems/confusion have come up, our data service isn't located outside of our application and as far as I know cannot be accessed via a reference to an internal URL. It is a "Connected Service Package" that we have to invoke via a C# function ie

```
using ServicePackage;
MyDataService = new DataService();

ViewModel.DataList = MyDataService.getData();
```

This all happens in a Controller Class. I know it's hackey and not how modern web app architecture is done, but it's the best the client could give us to work with. Believe me if we had a data-server or Web-API we could query we would be using $http or Ajax or any of the dozen other ways a View can pull data from an *external* source.

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJS?  If you're using AngularJS (and I'm guessing you are), you'd use the `$http` library.  There's excellent documentation on the AngularJS doc site.

Comment: We are using AngularJS, but our Data isn't coming directly from a server or a Database. Business Requirements abstract the Data Request into a C# API call to a service, this has to happen in a controller outside of the view, the Data is then cached locally. The request that the Angular has to make is to a ViewModel that already exists locally in the application.

Comment: Can the data service be handled or based by Angular service? If so that will take care of the issue you asked and automatically update when data changes without the need for AJAX

Comment: Your requirements conflict with one another...you can't retrieve data from the Server-side api without either a page reload or an AJAX call.  SOMETHING has to call the service to update the local cache.  You should use the `$http` library to do that.

Comment: You can use `SignalR` instead. And push the data to UI whenever the server detects that there is a change. Better than hitting the server every 10 seconds.

Comment: @David L the Service isn't server-side. It's a locally installed Connected Service package that runs internally within the application. We make the service call in a C# function by invoking "MyLocalServiceInstance.GetData()"

Comment: @user3776749 "Service isn't server-side. It's a locally installed"...I think there is maybe some terminology confusion: when you're talking about a web application, the bit which is part of the C# MVC part is generally referred to as the server-side, and the bit which runs in browser (HTML and Javascript) is the client-side. Of course if your MVC app then makes a call to _another_ server (e.g. your data service API), you'd have to make a distinction between the two servers when describing the flow of data.

Comment: @ADyson this is correct. My apologies. But I still can't access the service call via a url etc in order to load the data directly from the service into the View. In fact that kind of feels like it would break the whole point of MVC.

Comment: @user3776749 No need to apologise, it helps to try and describe what's happening in consistent terminology which everyone is likely to understand. If you can do that for this situation, we'll all probably grasp it a lot better.